# Add Stream data to signature dictionary using itext Sharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I'd like to include some kind of private information in a signature dictionary (without invalidating the signature, of course). I suppose I have to include it in the PDFName.CONTENTS entry (because contents is not covered by the signature), but Im stuccked here and I am not be able to progress.

Simplyfing, I get the next code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfOrigen);
FileStream os = new FileStream(pdfDestino, FileMode.Create);
PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
appearance.Reason = razon;
appearance.Location = localizacion;


IExternalSignature pks = new    X509Certificate2Signature(pk,DigestAlgorithms.SHA1); 
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

///this doesn't works             
PdfDictionary sv = new PdfDictionary();
sv.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfName("MyPrivateData"));
```

I know there is someting left to include it in the PDF, but I don't know what.
I even get the AcroField Signature but I don't know how to put the PdfDictionay inside:

```
AcroFields acroFields = new    PdfReader(pdfOrigen).AcroFields;
List<string> names = acroFields.GetSignatureNames();


foreach (var name in names)
{
PdfDictionary dict = acroFields.GetSignatureDictionary(name); 
}
```

Any clue, please?

Comment: *I suppose I have to include it in the PDFName.CONTENTS entry (because contents is not covered by the signature)* - that it's a bad idea, at last as you do it. The **Contents** are not *covered* by the signature because they *contain* the signature. If you put something else there, you obviously invalidate the signature. For some better alternative please first indicate whether the private data you want to add is fixed or may change later on.

Comment: Seems like @JulioLoizaga is trying to do something that is not compatible with digital signatures in PDF. Even if a different ByteRange would be defined for the private data, the signatures would never be PAdES compliant.

Comment: Sorry, I don't explain very well what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do is exactly that: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957941/attach-hidden-biometric-data-to-a-digital-signature-on-a-pdf). I have read the Digital Signatures for PDf Documents, among with the ABC for PDF with iText, and the iText in Action (thanks Bruno, I'm in debt with you.), but I'm a c# dev., and I have not a deep knowledge about pdf internal objects. I have manage to digitally sign a PDF (LTV). But I need to put some data in the Signature and I don't know exactly how. There is some example I could study?